# Pasting a range of columns in a data frame [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining

In a data frame, I am trying to paste contents of a range of columns (from `df$first` to `df$last`) into a new single column `df$merged`.

Contents of the columns are text strings. The number of columns in between `df&first` and `df$last` is variable. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
df$merged <- paste(df$first:df$last)
```

If name of every column to be merged were available as shown in example below, it does work fine.

```
df$merged <- paste(df$first, df$second, df$third,df$last)
```

But the nature of work is such that only the headers of the first and the last column names are known via user input.

Comment: Could you post a sample data? Otherwise, SO users cannot help you much.

Comment: shot in the dark: `do.call(paste, df[do.call(seq, as.list(grep(paste('first', 'last', sep = '|'), names(df))))])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tidyr::unite` to unite all columns between two columns. Use the `sep` argument if you want a different separator.

```
library('tidyverse')
df <- tribble(
  ~before_first, ~first, ~second, ~last, ~after_last,
            'a',    'c',     'e',   'h',         'j',
            'b',    'd',     'f',   'i',         'k'
)

df %>%
  unite(merged, first:last)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   before_first merged after_last
# *        <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
# 1            a  c_e_h          j
# 2            b  d_f_i          k
```